# Pixelated paint strokes on transparent Blender-created texture

Tags: transparency, texture-painting

Version: 2.76b, Renderer: Cycles

I have a material on an object. This material is made up of two textures: One created in Photoshop, which is semi-complete, and a second one that was created within Blender that has it's alpha channel decreased to zero.

I want to add painted details to the object on this transparent texture, so that I can export that texture into Photoshop and use it as a layer.

I also want to paint on this transparent texture while both textures are displayed in the 3D view. So, I have to change the shading mode to Material, which shows the 'finalized' material with both textures mixed together.

However, when I paint in the view the strokes have pixelated edges, despite them being completely normal in other rendering modes (these are useless as Renderered is laggy while painting and Solid/Texture modes do not show the finalized material, obviously). This is an obvious issue as I'm not able to see what the 'real' stroke looks like on the finalized material.

[image: Pixelated strokes in Material shading mode]

I may have tracked the problem down to the fact that I'm painting on a transparent texture. When the alpha is put back to 100%, the strokes are correctly smooth, but then it's an opaque image when exported to Photoshop, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to do this non-destructive way of painting textures or do I have to simply paint on the original semi-complete diffuse texture and export that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard Marklew, a mod at BlenderArtists.org answered my question:
[Fix](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?386863-Painting-on-alpha-causes-pixelated-edges-to-strokes-Quick-strokes-make-straight-lines&p=2972959&viewfull=1#post2972959)

[image]

It seems I was supposed to hook up the transparent texture's Alpha to "Fac" of the Mix Shader in the node editor. Fixed it easily.

Edit: I'll mark this as the Answer in a couple of days due to the account limit.